# What is the formula for cumulative compound interest?

Tags: finance, applications, derivation-of-formulae

I would like to start with a principal amount (P) in year 0, then add compound interest (C) to it for year 1, and then add that total value to the starting amount. So for example:

P=1000
C=2.5%

For three years growth, the outputs would be:

```
Year 0 1000.00
Year 1 2025.00    1000+(1000*1.025)
Year 2 3075.63    1000+(1000*1.025)+(1000*1.025*1.025)
Year 3 4152.52    1000+(1000*1.025)+(1000*1.025*1.025)+(1000*1.025*1.025*1.025)
```

What would the mathematical formula be for that please?

Comment: This is like, compounded compound interest. But you should just use the geometric series

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Given principal $P$ and interest rate $c>0$, at the end of year $t$ you have

$$P(1+(1+c)+...+(1+c)^t)=P\frac{(1+c)^{t+1}-1}{c}.$$

Comment: This is not right, IMHO. I agree with with the answer of Doug M.

Comment: @callculus42 I appreciate your comment, but Doug's answer does not include a $k=0$
 term in the summation whereas OP's post does.

Comment: Yes, but there are 3 payments only for t=n=3, not four  Here are the results of Andyguest13 and DougM: [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1000%2B%281000*1.025%29%2B%281000*1.025*1.025%29%2B%281000*1.025*1.025*1.025%29), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1000*%5Cfrac%7B1.025*%281.025%5E3%29-1%7D%7B1.025-1%7D). They are equal.

Comment: @callculus42 Please read the posts again very carefully.  What you have shared is based on exactly the expression I have written! [*This*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1000*%5Cfrac%7B1.025*%281.025%5E3-1%29%7D%7B1.025-1%7D) is what Doug M wrote.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the inconvenience But the good thing is that it is clarified now. I've overread  one payment :-(    +1

Answer (score 0):

That would be the future value of an annuity.

You receive $\$1000$ each year, and you invest the proceeds at $2.5\%.$  How much do you have at the end of $n$ years?

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^n 1000(1.025)^k$

That is a geometric series and we have a formula for that.

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^n 1000(1.025)^k = 1000\frac {1.025(1.025^n-1)}{1.025-1}$